# Linear and circular distance to horizon

Tags: geometry

I recently had a chance to go to a sea-shore and to also ponder the question:

*"What is the farthest point on the horizon that I can **theoretically** see, ignoring the effects of fog, clouds, waves, tide, and non-uniform curvature of Earth?"*

So, I got to work, and derived the formula thus:

Assuming...

- Earth to be a perfect sphere of radius, `r`;
- My height (at eye-level) to be, `h`; and
- The linear distance to the horizon to be, `d`;

Then,

$(r+h)^2 = d^2 + r^2$    (via Pythagoras theorem)

Or,

$d = (h^2 + 2rh) ^.5$

Also, the curved distance, `c`, to the horizon, would be:

$c = r . arccos (r / (r+h) )$

**However, here begins my difficulty.** When I substitute the values...

```
r = 6370 km
h = 180 cm   (or, 6 ft)
```

... I get,

```
d = 4.58 km   (reasonable, appears correct)
c = 274 km    (!!!)
```

... which doesn't make sense to me!

Why **so much** difference between `c` and `d`? Intuitively, I am expecting `c` to be very close to `d`. Why? Because, the surface of Earth is more or less flat, and when dealing with a linear distance, `d`, in the vicinity of merely `5 km`, the curved distance, `c`, should also be very close to `d`. Isn't it?

Where am I wrong in my **intuitive thinking** (as, afaik, my formula and computation are correct)?

Comment: I think maybe you just punched it in wrong. For me (in radians mode): `6370 / 6370.0018 INV COS * 6370` I get 4.7887. I know this is an old post, but I was just trying to calc something similar. It took me a little while to get it right, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you using to calculate this? Since $r/(r+h)$ is *very* close to 1, your (correct) formula for $c$ will be very sensitive to small precision errors in computing arccos. With an inexpensive calculator I got a result close to your 274 km, but when I asked Mathematica for the result I got an answer that was for all practical purposes equal to the straight-line distance, 4.78874 km.

Comment: O boy! THAT never occurred to me, and could never have - so I'm glad I posted this here. Now, I used `gnome-calculator` on Ubuntu 13.x, which I thought was an 'arbitrary precision' calculator. Apparently, it's not. My $r/(r+h)$ came out to be `0.99999971`.

Comment: Rick, since I'm not familiar with Mathematica, would you also post the function (or, the relevant code snippet) you used to calculate $r/(r+h)$ to arbitrary precision? Thanks.

Comment: @Harry Mathematica is a very powerful computer algebra program. It's also very expensive. However there's a free program that runs on the same engine. Check out [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/). Using this on your problem the linear distance is 4.788737 km and the circular distance is 4.788736 km, so the two differ by about a millimeter

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Btw, I found out that `/usr/bin/bc -l` can also do the job; the `-l` option uses a precision of 20 digits which can give you a value that is fairly precise, and if you want more precision, you can specify `scale=50` or higher inside your `bc` script.